# Loading 2 Arrays From Comma Delimited .txt File using Split Method C#

Tags: c#, arrays, visual-studio-2015, split, console-application

I'm trying to load the data from a comma delimited .txt file and put the information in 2 parallel arrays. The .txt file holds two columns of data, StudentName & StudentGrades.

Its looks similar to this...

Sally,67
Frank,32
John, 98

I'm trying to use the split method to read the comma delimited file, however I've tried many different ways to get this to work with no luck. The error that I am getting is "Cannot implicitly convert type string[] to string"

If I put the .txt data each on seperate lines and remove the split method from the code it works fine. However I need the file to be comma delimited.

```
 public static void LoadArray()
    {

        StreamReader studentInfoStreamReader = new StreamReader("LittleRecord2.txt");

        for (counter = 0; counter < 21; counter++)
        {
            if (studentInfoStreamReader.Peek() != -1) // CHECK TO SEE IF END OF FILE
            {

                studentName[counter] = (studentInfoStreamReader.ReadLine().Split(','));   // CODE WITH ERROR
                studentGrade[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(studentInfoStreamReader.ReadLine());        
            }
        }

        studentInfoStreamReader.Close(); 
    }

    public static void OptionOne()
    {
        LoadArray();

        Console.WriteLine("Student Name".ToString().PadRight(20) + ("Student Grade".ToString().PadRight(5)));
        Console.WriteLine();

        for (int c = 0; c < counter; c++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", studentName[c].PadRight(20), studentGrade[c].ToString().PadRight(5));
        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because `string.Split()` returns an array and you're assigning it to a scalar value. Store the split result in a new array variable and then assign its elements separately:

```
public static void LoadArray()
{
    StreamReader studentInfoStreamReader = new StreamReader("LittleRecord2.txt");
    for (counter = 0; counter < 21; counter++)
    {
        if (studentInfoStreamReader.Peek() != -1) // CHECK TO SEE IF END OF FILE
        {
            var splitLine = studentInfoStreamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
            studentName[counter] = splitLine[0];
            studentGrade[counter] = splitLine[1];
        }
    }
    studentInfoStreamReader.Close(); 
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Dmitry. Your solution worked perfectly for me. I appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

The `Split` method returns an array. In your case when you split using the comma, it will result in an array with 2 items. The first item at index 0 is the name and the 2nd item at index 1 is the grade:

```
var splitParts = (studentInfoStreamReader.ReadLine().Split(','));
studentName[counter] = splitParts[0];
studentGrade[counter] = Convert.ToInt32(splitParts[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of parallel arrays, it would be much more efficient to use a class.  Also unless your file has millions of entries reading the whole file into memory would probably be much quicker:

```
class Student
{
    public string name = "";
    public int grade = 0;
    public Student()
    {

    }
}
List<Student> GetStudents(string fileName)
{
    return (from string line in System.IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileName)
            let data = line.Split(",".ToArray())
            select new Student { name = data[0], grade = int.Parse(data[1]) }).ToList();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string[] x = studentInfoStreamReader.ReadLine().Split(',');
studentName[counter] = x[0];  
studentGrade[counter] = x[1];
```